# Bean vazio com PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Criei uma página com um `datatable` e para cadastrar algo eu exibo o `form` de cadastro num `p:dialog` do PrimeFaces funciona perfeitamente, mas quando crio o layout do PrimeFaces para colocar minha pagina dentro do layout e inicio um novo cadastro digito as informações e salvo, o objeto chega vazio no meu bean, e nem passa pela validação do beanValidator também.

Lembrando que a pagina funciona ok, mas quando coloco ela dentro deste layout do PrimeFaces dá esse problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```

```
<!--<ui:define name="metadata"></ui:define>-->

<ui:define name="title">Cadastro de Grupo de Empresas</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content" id="content">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{grupoEmpresasBean.consultar}"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <h:form id="form-lista">

        <p:messages id="messages-geral"  closable="true"/>

        <p:toolbar id="toolbar" style="margin-top:5px;">

            <f:facet name="left">
                <p:commandButton value="Incluir" icon="ui-icon-document" title="Incluir" 
                    action="#{grupoEmpresasBean.prepararInclusaoEdicao}"
                    process="@this" update="grupoEmpresa-dialogo"
                    oncomplete ="PF('cadastroGrupoEmpresa').show()">

                    <p:resetInput target="grupoEmpresa-dialogo"></p:resetInput>
                </p:commandButton>

                <span class="ui-separator">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical" title="Incluir" />
                </span>

                <p:commandButton value="Editar" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar"                        
                    disabled="#{grupoEmpresasBean.grupoEmpresaSelecionada == null}"
                    process="@this" update="grupoEmpresa-dialogo"                       
                    oncomplete ="PF('cadastroGrupoEmpresa').show()">

                    <p:resetInput target="grupoEmpresa-dialogo"></p:resetInput>

                    <f:setPropertyActionListener 
                        value="#{grupoEmpresasBean.grupoEmpresaSelecionada}" 
                        target="#{grupoEmpresasBean.grupoEmpresasInclusaoEdicao}">
                    </f:setPropertyActionListener>

                </p:commandButton>

                <p:commandButton value="Excluir" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir"
                    action="#{grupoEmpresasBean.excluirGrupoEmpresas}"
                    process="@this" update="listaGrupo messages-geral toolbar"
                    disabled="#{grupoEmpresasBean.grupoEmpresaSelecionada == null}" />              

            </f:facet>

        </p:toolbar>

        <p:dataTable value="#{grupoEmpresasBean.todosGruposEmpresas}" var="grupo"  emptyMessage="Nehum Grupo Cadastrado!!!" 
            id="listaGrupo" rows="10" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" style="margin-top:5px;"
            selection="#{grupoEmpresasBean.grupoEmpresaSelecionada}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{grupo.id}" >

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":mainForm:form-lista:toolbar"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":mainForm:form-lista:toolbar"/>
            <p:ajax event="page" update=":mainForm:form-lista:toolbar" listener="#{grupoEmpresasBean.desabilitaToolbar}" />

            <f:facet name="header">Grupos</f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Id" rendered="false" sortBy="#{grupo.id}">
                <f:facet name="header"> 
                    <h:outputText styleClass="datatable-header" value="Id" style="float:left;"/>
                </f:facet>                  
                <h:outputText styleClass="datatable-row" value="#{grupo.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{grupo.nomeGrupoEmpresa}">
                <f:facet name="header"> 
                    <h:outputText styleClass="datatable-header" value="Grupo" style="float:left;"/>
                </f:facet>          
                <h:outputText styleClass="datatable-row" value="#{grupo.nomeGrupoEmpresa}" style="float:left;"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column width="20%"  sortBy="#{grupo.cnpj}">
                <f:facet name="header"> 
                    <h:outputText styleClass="datatable-header" value="CNPJ" style="float:left;"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText styleClass="datatable-row" value="#{grupo.cnpj}" style="float:left;"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column width="20%"  sortBy="#{grupo.nomeProprietario}">
                <f:facet name="header"> 
                    <h:outputText styleClass="datatable-header" value="Proprietário" style="float:left;"/>
                </f:facet>              
                <h:outputText styleClass="datatable-row" value="#{grupo.nomeProprietario}"/>
            </p:column>     

        </p:dataTable>

        <p:dialog header="Incluir Grupo" widgetVar="cadastroGrupoEmpresa" id="grupoEmpresa-dialogo" appendTo="@(body)"
            resizable="false" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true" >

            <p:messages id="grupoEmpresa-dialogo-messages" />

            <p:defaultCommand target="cmdSalvarCadastroGrupoEmpresa" scope="grupoEmpresa-dialogo"/>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel-grupoEmpresa">

                <p:outputLabel styleClass="form-label"  for="nome-grupo">Nome do Grupo</p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText styleClass="form-text" id="nome-grupo" size="60" maxlength="100" value="#{grupoEmpresasBean.grupoEmpresasInclusaoEdicao.nomeGrupoEmpresa}" />

                <p:outputLabel styleClass="form-label" value="CNPJ" for="cnpj"/>
                <p:inputMask mask="99.999.999/9999-99" id="cnpj" size="18" maxlength="18" value="#{grupoEmpresasBean.grupoEmpresasInclusaoEdicao.cnpj}" />

                <p:outputLabel styleClass="form-label" value="Proprietário" for="proprietario"/>
                <p:inputText id="proprietario" size="60" maxlength="100" value="#{grupoEmpresasBean.grupoEmpresasInclusaoEdicao.nomeProprietario}" />       

                <h:outputLabel/>
                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="cmdSalvarCadastroGrupoEmpresa" 
                    action="#{grupoEmpresasBean.salvarGrupoEmpresas}" 
                    process="grupoEmpresa-dialogo"
                    oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('cadastroGrupoEmpresa').hide()"
                    update="grupoEmpresa-dialogo-messages painel-grupoEmpresa listaGrupo toolbar">                      

                </p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>       


</ui:define>
```

```

Alguem já passou por este problema?

Comment: Já passei por esse problema. Uma pergunta: Você quer dizer que funciona fora do Dialog? Seria bom colocar também o código, ao invés do screenshot.

Comment: entao felipe ele funciona perfeito fora do layout unit do primefaces,  primeiro criei a pagina e fiz ela funcionar estava tudo ok, ai criei um template conforme se ve na imagem acima, ai adiciono minha pagina dentro do meu template, ai jah nao funciona rs, se eu chamar a pagina fora do template funciona perfeita

Comment: Foi exatamente meu caso... Verifique se o `p:dialog` está dentro de um `h:form`

Comment: esta sim, mandei o codigo da pagina

Comment: Vi agora. Experimenta criar um `h:form` dentro deste `p:dialog`. Eu precisei isolar alguns _forms_ em meu projeto.

Comment: coloquei o h:form dentro do dialog mas nada brow

Comment: Felipe acho que achei o problema amigo, o problema esta no appendTo="@(body)" eu tive que colocar esta propriedade no dialog porque sem esta propriedade ele trava o dialogo tambem, entendeu

Comment: Boa, cara. Testa, veja se funciona, e depois coloca a solução como resposta.

Comment: @IvoBarcelos conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino opa consegui sim bro

Comment: Posta a solução para ajudar outros usuarios @IvoBarcelos